# Can't vertically center both input text and suffix in the Flutter TextField widget

Tags: flutter, textfield, suffix

I'm having a hard time aligning input ext and suffix in TextField Flutter widget. I try to center them vertically but can't do that for some reason.

When I don't specify suffix, the input text is vertically centered as desired:
[image]
When I specify the suffix, the input text goes down while the suffix goes up so that none of them are vertically centered:
[image]

**My code:**

```
return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('test'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.grey.shade800,
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          horizontal: 20,
          vertical: 10,
        ),
        height: 70,
        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        child: TextField(
          style: TextStyle(
            textBaseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic,
            color: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 17,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
            decoration: TextDecoration.none,
          ),
          textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            suffix: Icon(
              Icons.clear,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
            suffixStyle: TextStyle(
              color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1.color,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
              fontSize: 17,
              textBaseline: TextBaseline.ideographic,
            ),
            border: InputBorder.none,
            hintText: "Search",
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

**The question:**

What should I do to center input text and suffix vertically?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap icon in `Transform.translate` and set propper offset to it